# How to use props in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I am wondering how to use props to work my code? Here is my code.

```
const weatherConditions = {

  Rain: {
    color: '#005BEA',
  },
  Clear: {
    color: '#f7b733',
  }
};

const Weather = ({ weather }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
            styles.weatherContainer,
            { backgroundColor: weatherConditions.weather.color }
        ]}/>
    );
};
```

But it does not work. Only the code below works. How to fix this? Help me.

```
const Weather = ({ weather }) => {

    return (
      <View
        style={[
            styles.weatherContainer,
            { backgroundColor: weatherConditions.Rain.color } // or { backgroundColor: weatherConditions.Clear.color }
        ]}
      >
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are telling your component to look for `weatherConditions.weather.color` but the key `weather` is being interpreted literally. The component is looking for the `weather` key inside `weatherConditions` and it won't find it.

What you need to do is to do is:

`backgroundColor: weatherConditions[weather].color`

The brackets ensure `weather` is interpreted as a variable and not the word weather.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the weather conditions via the prop **weather** and not weatherConditions. Can you try it with **weather.Rain.color**? It should work with that.